# htaccess rewrite to file with a hash (#) in it's name filename

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm moving an old site into an /archive sub directory of a the new website.  The site is all HTML has lots of fully qualified URL to when it wasn't in the archive folder (e.g. (`http://domain.com/pictures/home.html`).  This is fine as I have rewritten any unfound files to the /archive directory.

The problem is... a lot of these fully qualified URLs have # in the filename e.g. `http://domain.com/pictures/category#001.html`.  These are then linked to as `http://domain.com/pictures/category%23001.html`.  When the rewrite is applied to these URLs, the server doesn't find the file giving a 404 error, with the path truncated at the %23 (e.g. '/archive/pictures/category was not found on this server.')

I've tried using the [B] flag, which still gives the 404 error but the file path it gives does exist (e.g '/archive/pictures/category#001.html was not found on this server.').

If I navigate directly to the file in the archive directory using the `%23` in the URL(e.g. `http://domain.com/archive/pictures/category%23001.html`) then the everything works fine.  The only issue is when adding the /archive directory through the RewriteRule

The rule is simply this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /archive/$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

I've also tried replacing the rule with this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /archive/%{REQUEST_URI} [B,L,QSA]
```

But it has the same issue.

Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only way I could get the server to go to the file was to redirect to it, instead of rewriting the URL, using the following code (R=302 flag added).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /archive/$1 [R=302,B,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NE` flag here (which avoids escaping):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ((?!archive/).*) /archive/$1 [NE,L,NC]
```

Comment: Using the `NE` flag still didn't work for me unfortunately.  The only way I could achieve getting the file was to redirect to it

Comment: Did you also try: `[NE,L,NC,B]`?